# Error while doing OneHotEnconding in a DataFrame which has categories as "numbers" and "strings"

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, transform, one-hot-encoding

Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

one_hot = OneHotEncoder()
transformer = ColumnTransformer([("one_hot", 
                                  one_hot,
                                  cat_features)],
                                  remainder="passthrough")

transformed_X = transformer.fit_transform(mmp_filled) 

transformed_X
```

`cat_features` include columns with numbers (which are considered as categories) and strings:

Here is the Dataframe "mmp_filled" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWJQh.png)

The error is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_encode.py in _unique_python(values, return_inverse)
    134 
--> 135         uniques = sorted(uniques_set)
    136         uniques.extend(missing_values.to_list())

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
17 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_encode.py in _unique_python(values, return_inverse)
    139         types = sorted(t.__qualname__ for t in set(type(v) for v in values))
    140         raise TypeError(
--> 141             "Encoders require their input to be uniformly "
    142             f"strings or numbers. Got {types}"
    143         )

TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['float', 'str']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert them to `str` first :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mmp_filled = pd.DataFrame({'x1':['A','B','A'],'x2':[1,1,'2'],'x3':[1,3,5]})
cat_features = ['x1','x2']
mmp_filled[cat_features] = mmp_filled[cat_features].astype(str)

one_hot = OneHotEncoder()
transformer = ColumnTransformer([("one_hot", 
                                  one_hot,
                                  ['x1','x2'])],
                                  remainder="passthrough")

transformed_X = transformer.fit_transform()
```